# Cannot consume WCF service in desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-4.0

I created a WCF service that has a one way (void) method.

When I create a new Windows Forms application, I can add the service reference and call the method with no problems.

When I add the reference to the actual project we need it on, the reference doesn't even appear and the error cannot find namespace shows.

So while adding the service reference, in advanced I removed the reuse types check box and then the service is there but when I call the code I get an error on the line that initializes the service:

```
var smsService = new SMSWebMethod.ServiceClient();
```

Error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'SMSWebMethod.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

Here is the `<system.serviceModel>` section of the `app.config` file

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="url/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="SMSWebMethod.IService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: please post your endpoint configuration

Comment: Its all generated by VS2012 there it is.

Comment: why not try `var smsService = new SMSWebMethod.ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService");`? Is there an overload to pass the endpoint configuration name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems there was an config file overriding the app.config.